# Which congestion control algorithm is used by the TCP stack in OS X?

Tags: osx-mavericks, tcp

What congestion control algorithm is implemented in TCP in OSX 10.9? I would like to know if it uses NewReno, or something newer like Cubic in Linux.

Comment: So you want to know what congestion avoidance algorithm is used, is that the question? (See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532372/how-to-load-a-different-congestion-control-algorithm-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for the link, I'm gonna dig into it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OSX Yosemite it appears to be CUBIC. In the `sysctl -a` output I see

```
net.inet.tcp.newreno_sockets: 0
net.inet.tcp.cubic_sockets: 21
net.inet.tcp.use_newreno: 0
net.inet.tcp.cubic_tcp_friendliness: 0
net.inet.tcp.cubic_fast_convergence: 0
net.inet.tcp.cubic_use_minrtt: 0
```